# Keyboard delay recognizng any key pressed after ctrl+shift and work fine with any other 3 key combination

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, sony-vaio

I got a strange problem with Sony VAIO SVF-series laptop(windows10) keyboard.
When I hold ctrl+shift it stops recognizing any next pressed key for a random period between instant recognizing(very low probability) and ~2,5sec.
Here are some details:

Any other 3 keys combinations that exclude holding ctrl and shift together seems to work fine. They do fail instant recognition but very rarely and it feels like a simple lag that has nothing common with this problem and I never actually notice anything wrong until start looking for any issues.

If I continue holding ctrl+shift after 3rd key recognized and released and try to press another key - delay will appear again.

If I continue holding the third key after recognition it will continue knowing 3rd key pressed and recognize when it's released without any issues.

In any case, with or without 3rd key remains held, as soon as ctrl or shift released it starts working fine. Example: Hold ctrl+shift then press any 3rd key = delay. Release shift, continue hold ctrl, press and hold 'alt' then press any 3rd key = no delay. 10 out of 10 normal recognition. Guess it means it's not a hardware problem.

Got the latest enhanced ps/2 keyboard driver.
win10 updates checked.
External keyboards working fine.
Filter keys are off.
I have this problem since I got this pc from the previous owner and don't know if it were all along or just appears one day.
No viruses.
Did not install any soft that can somehow affect this keys combination.

Can someone please give any thought of what it can be? I'm kinda *completely* out of ideas.

Thank you.

Comment: upd: 
Safe mode shows pretty same delay even with 2x more free RAM and CPU resources so I dare to assume that it's unlikely have something with low CPU capacity or lack of other PC resourses.

This thing slowly getting me mad...

Comment: upd: reinstalling windows ain't solve that.
After all, I suppose it's "extended keyboard PS/2 PC/AT (101/102) keys" driver causing this problem.
When I connect an external keyboard it using HID Keyboard driver and working fine.
Maybe there's a way to use "non-extended" one? I don't use fn keys anyway.
Does someone know how to replace it in win10?
This delay thing really bothers me, can't even ctrl+shift+arrow in excel or ctrl+shift+t in chrome.
Any suggestion of what it can be would cheer me up at least.
Thanks.